# Как объединить две колонки текста в одну?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как объединить две колонки текста в одну, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
 <div class="right-col col">
   <span>1 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span>1 строчка правого столбца</span>
   <span>2 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span>2 строчка правого столбца</span>
   <span>3 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span>3 строчка правого столбца</span>
   <span>4 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span>4 строчка правого столбца</span>
</div>
```

Внутри  строк `span` могут быть также теги, их следует сохранить.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.left-col {
  background-color: red;
}
.right-col {
  background-color: orange;
}
 span {
 display: block;
 }
 .col {
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left-col col">
    <span>1 строчка левого блока</span>
    <span>2 строчка левого блока</span>
    <span>3 строчка левого блока</span>
    <span>4 строчка левого блока</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col col">
    <span>1 строчка правого блока</span>
    <span>2 строчка правого блока</span>
    <span>3 строчка правого блока</span>
    <span>4 строчка правого блока</span>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать, используя [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) + [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > * {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.left-col {
  background-color: red;
}
.right-col {
  background-color: orange;
}
span {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
   <span class="left-col">1 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span class="right-col">1 строчка правого столбца</span>
   <span class="left-col">2 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span class="right-col">2 строчка правого столбца</span>
   <span class="left-col">3 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span class="right-col">3 строчка правого столбца</span>
   <span class="left-col">4 строчка левого столбца</span>
   <span class="right-col">4 строчка правого столбца</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Проблема в том, что это должны быть именно два разных столбца, разделённые разными родителям. Не буду грузить объяснениями почему, так требует реализация некоторого функционала

Comment: сформулируйте четко, что вы хотите. Мне не понятно. Два разных столбца у вас в вопросе приведены. А как объединять по столбцам как раз по принципу, который вы описали - я показал

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы в верстке у вас было два столбца в дивах как в примере, а визуально это было одним, или что?

Comment: лучше нагрузите объяснениями, почему ваша реализация требует этого. Скорее всего это не то, что вам нужно

Comment: Попытаюсь  показать на примере. Есть сайт с переводами иностранных стихов на русский. Два языка находятся в разных столбцах. На мобильной версии их нужно объединить в один так, чтобы шли по очереди иностранная строчка, затем русская строчка и так до конца

Comment: вот так всё понятно) дайте, пожалуйста, текущую реализацию "как есть" Добавлю еще одно решение

Comment: Если вы про JS-реализацию, то её нет, только учусь такие сложные штуки делать, интернет молчит на запросы. Мне бы хотя бы начало подсказать, как это сделать, чтобы понять методологию. Если про HTML-разметку, то её минифицированный пример указан в шапке

Comment: Нет, ну решений много разных, я просто хочу понять что у вас есть сейчас и какое подойдет лучше. И js тут кстати не нужен

Comment: Понял, спасибо. По сути, один-в-один разметка https://i.ibb.co/WfVJxjY/image.png

Comment: В таком случае, не советую вам с помощью js, например, доставать из столбцов строки и перемещать. Это лишний код и вообще это будет ужасно выглядеть - костыли. Самое элегантное решение - вам нужен общий родитель с display: grid. Затем, добавляете строки в каком угодно порядке. Каждой строке задаете grid-area и с помощью grid-template-areas в родителе компонуете разметку для десктоп и мобильной версии с помощью media query. Здесь неплохая инструкция https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Эх, не получается

Comment: Добавьте свое решение в вопрос, помогу